# Javascript - Bowling game Simulator

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a bowling simulator with Javascript. I have created a function that takes a random number between 0 & 10. And at bowling you can throw 2 times per round. I managed to get 2 values back like 5 and 8 but the problem is that you cannot throw more than 10 pins at bowling. And I can't figure out how I get the value 4, 3, 2, 1 or 0 when i throw 6.

This is my code in a snippet...

```js
  var team1 = ["Jason", "Jake", "Jane", "Joe"];
        var team2 = ["John", "Drake", "Nick", "Joseph"];

  var rounds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  var pin = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

  for (var team1 = 0; team1 < 2; team1++) {
   console.log(getRandomPin(team1));
  }

  for (var team2 = 0; team2 < 2; team2++) {
   console.log(getRandomPin(team2));
  }

  function getRandomPin(min, max) {
      min = Math.ceil(0);
      max = Math.floor(11);
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (11 - 0)) + 0;
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you find an answer to your question, please do not remove the initial content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need have a variable to keep track of how many pins are left. Don't forget to reset it between rounds.

```
var team1 = ["Jason", "Jake", "Jane", "Joe"];
var team2 = ["John", "Drake", "Nick", "Joseph"];

var rounds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var pins = 11;
for (var team1 = 0; team1 < 2; team1++) {
    console.log('Adam', getRandomPin());
}

pins = 11;
for (var team2 = 0; team2 < 2; team2++) {
    console.log('Tom', getRandomPin());
}

function getRandomPin() {
    var pinsKnocked = Math.floor(Math.random() * pins);
    pins -= pinsKnocked;
    return pinsKnocked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to keep track of how many pins are left and how many was striked... Here I used just one 'team', but you can easily do this to two or more teams.
Please, take a look and see if this helps you.

```js
    var team1 = ["Jason", "Jake", "Jane", "Joe"];
    var team2 = ["John", "Drake", "Nick", "Joseph"];

    var rounds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    var pin = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

    var aux2 = 0;
    var maxVal = 11;
    for (var team2 = 0; team2 < 2; team2++) {
       maxVal = maxVal - aux2;
       console.log('Pins Remaining: ' + (maxVal-1));
       var pins = getRandomPin(0, maxVal);
       aux2 += pins;
       if (pins == 10){
          console.log('Round-' + (team2 + 1) +' | STRIKE!');
          break; //leaves the function because when strike occurs no second round is played
       }else{       
          console.log('Round-' + (team2 + 1) +' | pins striked: ' + pins);
       }
    }    
    console.log('Total pins striked: ' + aux2);
    aux2 = 0;
    maxVal = 11;    
    
    function getRandomPin(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My code is a little verbose, but I tried to add comments explaining everything I was thinking when I wrote it. It could still be optimized further, but I hope this gets you thinking in a slightly different way about the problem. One such optimization that I would make next would be to move the duplicate code (the two similar loops) into a single function. Another optimization is to add an `if` statement to skip the second throw if the first throw scored 10 pins. Anyway, here you go:

```js
var team1 = ["Adam", "Ayman", "Matthijs", "Joey"];
var team2 = ["Tom", "Afzal", "Jef", "Anouar"];
var rounds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

// Let's loop over all the rounds
for (var roundNumber = 1; roundNumber <= rounds.length; roundNumber++) {
    // This will tell us what round we are on
    console.log('******Round Number:', roundNumber);
    // Let's let team number 1 go first
    console.log('***Team One');
    for (var i = 0; i < team1.length; i++) {
        // There are always 10 pins standing in the beginning
        var standingPins = 10;
        // The we see how many pins are hit first
        var pinsHitFirst = getRandomPin(standingPins);
        // The number of pins left standing
        standingPins = standingPins - pinsHitFirst;
        // and the number of pins the player hit the second attempt
        var pinsHitSecond = getRandomPin(standingPins);
        console.log(team1[i] + '\'s Score: ', pinsHitFirst, pinsHitSecond);
    }    // Now it's time for team number 2
    console.log('***Team Two');
    for (var i = 0; i < team2.length; i++) {
        // There are always 10 pins standing in the beginning
        var standingPins = 10;
        // The we see how many pins are hit first
        var pinsHitFirst = getRandomPin(standingPins);
        // The number of pins left standing
        standingPins = standingPins - pinsHitFirst;
        // and the number of pins the player hit the second attempt
        var pinsHitSecond = getRandomPin(standingPins);
        console.log(team2[i] + '\'s Score: ', pinsHitFirst, pinsHitSecond);
    }
}

// This will allow us to randomly select the number of pins hit
// based on how many pins were still standing
function getRandomPin(remainingPins) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * remainingPins);
}
```